# How to implement rolling window (key level) in Apache Beam?

Tags: python, spark-streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam with python SDK to build data pipelines for streaming data (in my case google PubSub).

Consider this scenario:
[image]
Assume that event time ~ processing time (i.e. no late events)

Now for this snapshot, I want to calculate two sets of features:

- Cumulative count per user (triggered at every event)
- number of events in the past 60 seconds (triggered at every event)

For the first case (Cumulative count per user), I have written the following code and it is working perfectly:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options = options) as p:
    data = (
    p | 'read data' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB_PATH)
      | 'add timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestamp())
      | 'parse data' >> beam.ParDo(ParseEvent())  
    )
    
    moving_sum = (
    data 
        | 'global_window' >> beam.WindowInto(windowfn = beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
                                             trigger=beam.trigger.Repeatedly(beam.trigger.AfterCount(1)),
                                             accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
        | 'extract amount' >> beam.ParDo(CollectAmount())
        | 'sum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        | 'convert to dict' >> beam.ParDo(Convert2Dict())
        | 'cumsum_to_pqsl' >> relational_db.Write(source_config=source_config,table_config=table_config2)   
    )
```

For the second set of features, I am unable to figure out a logic which will give me the number of events per user in the last 60 seconds whenever a new event is read for that user. This use case is different from fixed window and sliding window, here the window (60 seconds) is dependent on the event.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

None of the built-in Beam window fns support this kind of windowing. Instead, you could consider using [state and timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/). Store each element in state, set a timer for 60 seconds after each element comes in, and when the timer fires read the state to sum over the relevant events.

Comment: Won't the above method emit the result 60 seconds after the element is read (because the timer is set 60 seconds after the element comes in). Also since I am storing each element in a state, this will give me cumulative count. What I want is as follows:
1. When an element (let's say at event time = T0) is processed, count of the elements in the last 60 seconds i.e. [T0-60,T0] range 
2. I want to emit results only when an element is encountered (as these emissions are being used to trigger my model service)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In this case, you could set a timer for the timestamp of the element, and when it fires, emit the number of elements in your state that fall into the [T-60, T] range. (You have to do this after the timer fires, because elements may come in after order.) You can also clear elements older than 60 seconds in your state to avoid it growing unboundedly over time.